# Method for extracting azimuth from Polyline object

Tags: android-studio, openstreetmap

I have created a polyline between `myPoint1` and `myPoint2`.

```java
    private GeoPoint myPoint1;
    private GeoPoint myPoint2; 
    private List<GeoPoint> polylinePoints = new ArrayList<>();
    private Polyline myPolyline; 

    ...
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    ...
    
    polylinePoints.add(myPoint1);
    polylinePoints.add(myPoint2);
    myPolyline.setPoints(polylinePoints);

    ...
```

Is there a method that can be invoked on `myPolyline` to extract the azimuth (0° to 360°) from myPoint1 to myPoint2, or for that matter, can it be extracted in any other way?

PS: `myPoint1` and `myPoint2` are two points in a `MapView` object.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I have worked out a custom method, which does exactly what was required ("bearing" is another word for "azimuth"):

```
    private String returnBearingString(GeoPoint pointA, GeoPoint pointB){

    double latitudeA = (pointA.getLatitude() / 360) * (2 * Math.PI);
    double longitudeA = (pointA.getLongitude() / 360) * (2 * Math.PI);
    double latitudeB = (pointB.getLatitude() / 360) * (2 * Math.PI);
    double longitudeB = (pointB.getLongitude() / 360) * (2 * Math.PI);
    double deltaL = longitudeB - longitudeA;

    double x = Math.cos(latitudeB) * Math.sin(deltaL);
    double y = (Math.cos(latitudeA) * Math.sin(latitudeB)) - (Math.sin(latitudeA) * Math.cos(latitudeB) * Math.cos(deltaL));

    double bearingRadians = Math.atan2(x,y);
    int bearingInt = (int) ((bearingRadians/(2 * Math.PI))*360);

    if(bearingInt < 0){
        bearingInt = 360 + bearingInt;
    }

    String text = bearingInt + "°";

    return text;
```

}